# Export dictionary externally in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, export

I am trying to look at how each input variables contribute to my Random Forest classifier. There is an `explain()` tools in `ee.Classifier` but the portal always shows:

```
 Dictionary (Error)
 Earth Engine capacity exceeded.
```

It is a dictionary, is there any way to export the explanation results so I can check it externally like in Excel?

```
var trainedClassifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(10).train({
    features: training, 
    classProperty: 'LCZ', 
    inputProperties: bands
    });

    var classified = composite.classify(trainedClassifier);

    print('explain', trainedClassifier.explain());
```

I don't know what code to write for exporting then.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
var rfExplain = trainedClassifier.explain();

Export.table.toDrive(
  ee.FeatureCollection([ee.Feature(null,rfExplain)]);
```